# "Forms" authentication is enabled but still see "Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

Tags: asp.net, asp

"Forms" authentication is enabled in web.config but I still see:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

I think it's a file permission problem. I just added a new website to IIS. is there any thing I'm missing?

Comment: Have you enabled anonymous authentication on the web application ? Have you tested file system access permissions ?

Comment: Thanks, yes enabled anonymous authentication but how can I test file system access permissions ?

Comment: It depends on the version of IIS you're running. On 6.1 and later, select the root of the web app (or site), click on "basic settings" on the action pane and click "Test settings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using forms authentication, it is traditional to redirect a request that is not authenticated/anonymous to the logon page. You should also disable Windows authentication if using IIS 7.0 Integrated mode.